# google maps api -> DirectionsRenderer -> Plotting Multiple Routes -> Stop routes from showing that bypass a waypoint?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a map that will show multiple routes within a gmap.  The farther I have gotten into coding, I have noticed that at certain times the map display a route that bypasses a waypoint that I have pushed.  The route is correct but there is a portion of the route that is shown as an accessible route that shouldn't be as it completely bypasses a waypoint between the destination and origin.  I have been attempting to remove this, but I have had no luck.  A very good example of this occurring is actually on in googles code examples. :

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable.html

As you can see in the above example it is showing that the route can bypass Bourke.  I don't see why it is showing this as a possibility.  Not sure if anyone has run into this before, but if you have and know how to change this I would greatly appreciate some advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further review of my code I found that I had an issue with setting the destination and origin incorrectly.  (variable mishmash)  This was causing some other issues, but in conjunction with this previous issue I found another and that was that the order in which your waypoints are pushed to the array is very integral to the way in which the route is rendered. By fixing the destination and origin and then pushing my waypoints in the route's correct order I was able to fix the issue described above.